# Change Zoom Settings in Outlook via C# VSTO

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to change the Zoom Percentage of a Mail Item via C# or VB, that doesnt matter. Ive created an Project but its not possible to access the corret variable. Is this even possible?
I dont want to change the Font Size, just the Zoom Percentage while writing an email.
NOT of the Whole Outlook, just of the Mail Item.
thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Word object model for changing the zoom level of a particular mail item shown in the inspector window:

```
Dim Document As Object
'
Set Document = inspector.WordEditor
Document.Windows.Item(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 200 '200 %
```

The [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. Note, you need to add a COM reference to the Word object model to get access to the Word methods and properties.

You may find the [Adjusting Outlook's Zoom Setting in Email](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/adjust-outlooks-zoom-setting/) article helpful.